# Correct usage of non-temporal store(_mm_stream_si64)

Tags: c, x86, intrinsics

I have a function, as described below, where I want to write the same behavior as written in line `(1)` with `non-temporal store`. Is the usage of `_mm_stream_si64` in line `(2)` a correct way to reproduce line `(1)`?

```
void func(void *dest, void *src){
   (1) *(void **)(dest) = src;
   (2) _mm_stream_si64(dest, src); 
}
```

I am not entirely sure I am using `_mm_stream_si64` correctly because supposedly it expects `__int64` type as a second parameter (`_mm_stream_si64(__int64* mem_addr, __int64 a)`). Though for `mem_addr`, I hope using `void *` should be fine.

Or is there any other intrinsic store I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only correct in 64-bit mode, where a `void*` is 64-bit.  But then yes, that's correct.  It's an 8-byte alignment-required store that's strict-aliasing safe (it doesn't care about C types, only bytes of memory, **like memcpy but with an alignment requirement**.)  So it's definitely safe if `dst` was correctly aligned to hold a `void*`.

Although `movnti` with 64-bit operand-size is only available at all in 64-bit mode, so the only time that would compile but be wrong is with `gcc -mx32` (32-bit pointers in 64-bit mode.)

You should include a `static_assert( sizeof(src) == sizeof(int64_t) )`.  Or an `if(sizeof(src) == 4)` to select `_mm_stream_si32`.

Note that NT stores are generally only efficient if you're writing a full line *with NT stores* (all 64 bytes of a naturally-aligned 64-byte chunk). So a single `movnti` will often be worse for performance unless you're calling this or other wrapper functions for each element of a struct or something.